# html5 canvas resize a drawn line

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, drawing

I'm working on a HTML5 Canvas whiteboard.

I store all my elements on the stage in an array.

Now I added a drawing function. I can draw and select the drawn object.
Now I want to resize the object.

My Paint Class

```
class Paint {
    constructor(
        id="", coordinates =[], color = '', type="paint", x=0, y=0, width=0, height=0
    ) {
        this.id = id;
        this.coordinates = coordinates,
        this.fillColor = color;
        this.type = type;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        
    }

    update() {
        let { coordinates, color,x,y,width,height} = this;
        ctx.save();
        let xx;
        let yy;
      
        
        coordinates.map((dot,index) =>{

            if(index == 0)
            {
                x = dot.startX;
                y = dot.startY;
                xx = dot.mouseX;
                yy = dot.mouseY;
            }

            if(dot.startX < x)
            {
                x=dot.startX; 
            }
            if(dot.startY < y)
            {
                y=dot.startY; 
            }
            if(dot.mouseX>xx)
            {
                xx=dot.mouseX;
            }
            if(dot.mouseY>yy)
            {
                yy=dot.mouseY;
            }

            let startX =  (dot.startX - dx);
            let startY =  (dot.startY - dy);
            let mouseX =  (dot.mouseX - dx);
            let mouseY =  (dot.mouseY - dy);

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.lineWidth = 5;
            ctx.lineCap = 'round';
            ctx.strokeStyle = '#ACD3ED';
            ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
            ctx.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
            ctx.stroke();

        });
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = xx-x;
        this.height = yy-y;
    
        ctx.restore();
    }
}
```

A result could look like this:
[image: Drawing]

Positions are stored in this format:
[image]

If want to resize the drawing proportional if I drag a corner of the calculated rectangle.

I hope someone can help me with that problem.

thanks in advance
Frank

Comment: The code you show has nothing about resize ... What have you tried? what error are you getting?

Comment: I have no error code. The class shows how I create my object. And I need an idea how to resize it. I can drag the corners of the surrounding rectangle to do it. But I have no clue how to resize an object made out of a lot of small lines. mouseX and mouseY is a little bit wrong naming, because it's the end of the mini line.

Comment: Maybe resize the canvas element and redraw the whole canvas. That should do it instead of trying to manually scale each element with events

Comment: I think you mean to scale the element. I thought about that as well. But I think I the solution is something like, getting the center of the drawing calculate the distance of the dragged corner and increase or decrease each value by the distance amount, depending on if the the coordinate is left or right or above or below the center.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm close to a solution, but now I get some form deformations.

I calculate the center of the drawing and then I check each point, if it's position is lower or higher of the center and then I increase or decrease the position by the value of the distance between the start and end position of the corner that I'm dragging.

```
stageObjects[i].coordinates.map(dot=>{
    // upper left corner
    if(dot.startX<stageObjects[i].xCenter && dot.startY<stageObjects[i].yCenter)
    {
        dot.startX -= distance;
        dot.startY -= distance;
    }
    if(dot.mouseX<stageObjects[i].xCenter && dot.mouseY<stageObjects[i].yCenter)
    {
        dot.mouseX -= distance;
        dot.mouseY -= distance;
    }
    // upper right corner
    if(dot.startX>stageObjects[i].xCenter && dot.startY<stageObjects[i].yCenter)
    {
        dot.startX += distance;
        dot.startY -= distance;
    }
    if(dot.mouseX>stageObjects[i].xCenter && dot.mouseY<stageObjects[i].yCenter)
    {
        dot.mouseX += distance;
        dot.mouseY -= distance;
    }
    // lower left corner 
    if(dot.startX<stageObjects[i].xCenter && dot.startY>stageObjects[i].yCenter)
    {
        dot.startX -= distance;
        dot.startY += distance;
    }
    if(dot.mouseX<stageObjects[i].xCenter && dot.mouseY>stageObjects[i].yCenter)
    {
        dot.mouseX -= distance;
        dot.mouseY += distance;
    }
    // lower right corner 
    if(dot.startX>stageObjects[i].xCenter && dot.startY>stageObjects[i].yCenter)
    {
        dot.startX += distance;
        dot.startY += distance;
    }
    if(dot.mouseX>stageObjects[i].xCenter && dot.mouseY>stageObjects[i].yCenter)
    {
        dot.mouseX += distance;
        dot.mouseY += distance;
    }
})
```